# Disallow duplicate background images - CSS LINT

Tags: css, wordpress

I have the following CSS meant to display a background image with all browsers:

```
.single-product.postid-92613 .site-content, .single-product.postid-92613 header#masthead, .single-product.postid-92613 .site-footer, .single-product.postid-92613 .sfb-footer-bar {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3))), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)), url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/pic.jpg")!important;
  background-attachment: fixed!important;
  background-size: cover!important;
  background-position: 100% 0!important;}
```

CSS lint gives a warning that `background-image` is being called several times. Is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score -1):

Also add this in CSS:

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question. The problem - as described - is that the OP has multiple `background-image` declarations, which is considered a problem by CSS Lint. The OP wishes to disable the warnings generated by CSS Lint.